# Why won't finding polynomial whole number routes work?

Tags: ti-basic

So I want this to find me the roots of a polynomial. However, everytime I run it, it never gives me any roots, even if I use an obvious one like 2x-2. Why won't it work?

```
Input "Degree?",θ
Disp "Left to right"
Disp "coefficients"
1→V
For(Z,0,θ)
Input A
Q→R
P→Q
O→P
N→O
M→N
L→M
K→L
J→K
I→J
H→I
G→H
F→G
E→F
D→E
C→D
B→C
A→B
If V=1
Then
A→S
V=0
End
End

For(T,–A,A)
For(U,–W,W)
If T≠0
U/T→X

RX+Q→Y
YX+P→Z
ZX+O→Y
YX+N→Z
ZX+M→Y
YX+L→Z
ZX+K→Y
YX+J→Z
ZX+I→Y
YX+H→Z
ZX+G→Y
YX+F→Z
ZX+E→Y
YX+D→Z
ZX+C→Y
YX+B→Z


If Z=0
Then
Disp X
End
End
End



prgmRESET
```

RESET just resets the variable values. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Request: I have absolutely no idea what operation you are working off of, if you could please state that

Observation: You're using a lot of variables that haven't had any value assigned to them or initially cleared, I can see that you're trying to create a 'stream' of variables to work with, but if you do this without clearing the variables ahead of time then you create problems in your later calculations.

Coding Recommendations:

- You state V=0, which does nothing in this context, instead of assigning it a value
- You can change 'If T≠0' into just 'If T'
- In your third 'For()' statement, "W" is undefined in the code.
- You can change 'If Z=0:Then:Disp X:End', near the end of your code, into just 'If not(Z:Disp X'
- Move prgmRESET to the top of your program

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how you code is supposed to find the routes of a polynomial. Your error is most likely occurring somewhere in your mess of variable assigning/reassigning/swapping. I would redo your code using lists instead of basic variables.

---

If all you want to do is find the routes of a polynomial, I can give you a program for that.

```
:Prompt L1,X
:Repeat 1=dim(L1
    :dim(L1->dim(L3 
    :seq(L1(A)(Ans-A),A,1,Ans-1->L2
    :Repeat abs(Ans)<10^(-7
        :L1(1->L3(1
        :For(A,2,dim(L1
            :XL3(A-1)+L1(A->L3(A
        :End
        :Ans->B
        :L2(1->L3(1
        :For(A,2,dim(L2
            :XL3(A-1)+L2(A->L3(A
        :End

        :Ans^-1(AnsX-B->X
        :B
    :End
    :Disp X
    :L1(1->L2(1
    :For(A,2,dim(L1)-1
        :XL2(A-1)+L1(A->L2(A
    :End
    :L2->L1
:End
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. You use a whole lot of variables without ever clearing or defining them, which probably means that all of your values will be 0.

Also, recommendation for future TI-BASIC questions:

**PLEASE explain your variables.** There's nothing worse than having a mess of variables and expecting the reader to do detective work to find out what they're supposed to do. Plus, it's helpful for you as well when you decide to come back to it for troubleshooting.